# Android Gradle Plugin 3.0 Output apk to different directory

Tags: android, directory, android-gradle-plugin

I have recently upgraded to Gradle 3.0 and now find that the feature to rename the output APK has changed. I think I can get around that, but what I am wondering is whether I can still choose the target directory for the APK. We have existing software that uses a specific APK naming convention and directory structure that I want to maintain. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my current gradle build structure (simplified and renamed to protect the innocent):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 23
        versionName "23.23.23"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
        // Add the property 'myCustomProperty' to each product flavor and set the default value to 'customPropertyValue'
        flavor.ext.set('directoryPath', '')
        flavor.ext.set('apkName', '')
    }
    productFlavors {

        MyCompany {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = mycompany
        }

        Copper {
            applicationId c
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'copper'
        }

        Steel {
            applicationId 'com.company2.steel'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'steel'
        }

        Lead {
            applicationId 'com.company3.coal'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'coal'
        }

    }


    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def path = "C:/AndroidBuilds/MyBuilds/" + variant.productFlavors[0].directoryPath + "/"
            logger.error("Path = " + path)
            def SEP = "-"
            def apkName = variant.productFlavors[0].apkName
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
            if (apkName != '')
                flavor = apkName;
            def version = variant.versionCode
            def newApkName = path + version + SEP + flavor
            logger.error("newApkName = " + newApkName)
            output.outputFile = new File(newApkName + ".apk")
        }
    }
}
```

I know that there is now a "Flavor Dimension" which I will just default (I removed that just to make the code a wee bit clearer). The results of running this build should be that 4 different APKs would be generated and placed in their own directory structures, prefixed with the version number (eg "64-Iron.apk").

The naming is working by replacing with "outputfile", but the directory structure does not. Is there a new way to do this under the latest Gradle?

**UPDATE (FIXED)**

Thanks to the info provided by selected solution, for completeness, here is the final gradle config (again, cleaned to protect the innocent):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 23
        versionName "23.23.23"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors.whenObjectAdded { flavor ->
        // Add the property 'myCustomProperty' to each product flavor and set the default value to 'customPropertyValue'
        flavor.ext.set('directoryPath', '')
        flavor.ext.set('apkName', '')
    }
    productFlavors {

        MyCompany {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = mycompany
        }

        Copper {
            applicationId c
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'copper'
        }

        Steel {
            applicationId 'com.company2.steel'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'steel'
        }

        Lead {
            applicationId 'com.company3.coal'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            directoryPath = 'coal'
        }

    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def apkName = variant.productFlavors[0].apkName
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
            if (apkName != '')
                flavor = apkName;
            //add here your logic to customize the name of the apk
            outputFileName = "${variant.versionCode}-${flavor}.apk"
        }
        variant.assemble.doLast { assemble ->
            //copy the apk in another directory, add here your
            //logic to customize the destination folder
            copy {
                from variant.outputs*.outputFile
                into "C:/AndroidBuilds/MyBuilds//${variant.productFlavors[0].directoryPath}"
            }
            //if you don't want to delete the file after copying it comment the line below
            delete variant.outputs*.outputFile
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again MatPag!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Starting from Gradle 3.3.0 `assemble` property is deprecated. This is the new way to do this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        //add here your logic to customize the name of the apk
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
    variant.assembleProvider.configure { assemble ->
        assemble.doLast {
            //copy the apk in another directory, add here your
            //logic to customize the destination folder
            copy {
                from variant.outputs*.outputFile
                //for Windows
                into "C:/my_apks/${variant.dirName}"
            }
            //if you don't want to delete the file after copying it comment the line below
            delete variant.outputs*.outputFile
        }
    }
}
```

> in macOS/Linux you can use something like this for the destination
>   path:

```
into "${System.properties['user.home']}/my_apks/${variant.dirName}"
```

---

**OLD ANSWER (for AGP < 3.3.0):**
I've played a bit with Gradle 4.2.1 and AGP 3.0.0, and a possible solution is this one

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        //add here your logic to customize the name of the apk
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
    variant.assemble.doLast { assemble ->
        //copy the apk in another directory, add here your
        //logic to customize the destination folder
        copy {
            from variant.outputs*.outputFile
            into "C:/my_apks/${variant.dirName}"
        }
        //if you don't want to delete the file after copying it comment the line below
        delete variant.outputs*.outputFile
    }
}
```

I think it's a good starting point to customize the folders based on your needs :)

Comment: Sweet. Looks promising...let me play with it and see if it does the trick. thanks!

Comment: @StephenMcCormick let me know it ;)

Comment: After fixing a couple other Gradle issues, it worked like a charm! Thanks and awesome job!

Comment: @KapilRajput check the gradle version in the gradle-wrapper

Comment: @MatPag gradle version is 4.4

Comment: @KapilRajput that's strange, tried changing the Android Gradle Plugin version?

Comment: @MatPag I didn't tried on gradle 4.2 as i have to use gradle 4.4. please suggest me any other way if possible to copy apk in another location : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169963/copy-apk-file-from-build-location-to-some-other-location-in-gradle-4-4/

Comment: `assemble` has since (gradle plugin 3.3 I think) been deprecated. Need to use `getAssembleProvider()` instead.

Comment: @Mark i will check when i go home

Comment: Thanks! Hint: `variant.getAssembleProvider().configure { it.doLast { ...` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54343606/444761

Comment: @Mark thank you for your help. I've updated the answer :)