# Copy APK file from build location to some other location in gradle 4.4

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

As in `gradle` `4.4` it is not possible to change path of APK output file and we can't use absolute path for the apk's output now from the docs -  [**Modifying variant outputs at build time may not work**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#variant_output) so I searched on SO and found a solution that we can copy `apk` to our desired location after it gets build but I don't have much idea on gradle scripting and i am not able to call copy task. Can anyone help me.

code from my gradle :

```
    android {
    ................
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        if (variant.name.contains("Release")) {
             outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
     }
     assembleRelease {
        dependsOn copyDocs
    }
    }// end of android brace

    task copyApk(type: Copy) {
    from outputFileName
    into file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk")
   }
  }
```

From this way i am getting error :

> Could not get unknown property 'outputFileName' for task

Any idea how to copy apk file to another path? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it by running `copy` script in `gradle` file like this :

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.all {

copy {
      from file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/" + variant.name + "/release/${outputFileName}")
      into file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/")
     }
    delete file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/" + variant.name) // i don't want apk on this location so after successful copy i am deleting it
  }
 }
```

Comment: However, this copy process will take place BEFORE the APK is compiled and just move the previously compiled APK, not the latests one.

Comment: yeah, this does seem to copy the previous existing build artifacts.

Comment: you can wrap it in a `doLast` closure, like so: `applicationVariants.all { variant ->         def buildType = variant.buildType.name; def flavor = variant.flavorName; def flavorDir = "${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/$flavor"; def oldFile = "${project.name}-$flavor-${buildType}.apk"; def fromFile = file("$flavorDir/$buildType/$oldFile"); def intoDir = "${project.distsDirName}/$buildType/"; variant.assembleProvider.configure { it.doLast { copy { from fromFile; into file(intoDir); /* rename oldFile, "..." */ }; delete file(flavorDir) } } }`

Answer (score 3):

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        println variant.name
        if (variant.name.contains("release")) {
            outputFileName = new File("../", "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk")
            println outputFileName
        }
    }
}
```

and remove

```
task copyApk
```

Comment: we can't use absolute path for apk output in gadle 4.4, in previous gradle version i was doing it in the same way u suggested but this way is not supported in latest gradle

Comment: outputFileName = new File("../", "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk")
"../" is a relative path, you can replace with others etc "../../". I'm using gradle4.4, it works