# Issue with gradle when updating android studio 3.2.1 to 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have update my android studios 3.2.1 to 3.3 and sync project with gradle 4.10.1.
I getting error/warning like this,

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app
```

If I am wrong please suggest me.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: It's just a warning, you can ignore it. I've explained it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54343606/2444099