# Unexpected Gradle Warnings + Code Editor breakdown

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I've began getting few new Gradle Warnings when I'm trying to build the project, these are:

```
The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.
```

and

```
API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
```

And also today my Android Studio code editor is unable to resolve symbol R, when I'm trying to get resources - I belive it is connected.
I've tried rebuild, clean + rebuild, invalidating cashes - nothing seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? What's the version of the Android Build Tools Gradle plugin? What version of Gradle are you using? (You can check the version in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.)

Comment: @Edric Android Studio - 3.1.4

Comment: @Edric Gradle - 4.10.1; Android Plugin - 3.3.0

Comment: Where is `android.enableAapt2` defined?

Comment: And what about trying to compiling your app and running it on your phone? Does it cause any errors?

Comment: @Edric In gradle.properties (Project). It runs fine on phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using an **alpha/beta** version of **build tools gradle** file. Please select a stable version like `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0` or `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.3`.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with) post may help you.