# Update build.gradle 3.3.0 Breaks applicationVariants.all apk Assembly

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have just upgraded an Android project's build.gradle to use build version 3.3.0

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0
```

Doing so has created this warning:

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getAssemble(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app
```

It is caused by this code in the app build.gradle:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.assemble.doLast {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def apk = variant.outputs[0].outputFile
            File versionInfo = new File(apk.parent, "versionInfo.properties")
            versionInfo.text = "versionCode=${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}\nversionName=${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
            copy {
                from "${versionInfo}"
                into "$project.projectDir/temp_archive"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find where I can rewrite this to make the warning disappear. I tried to follow [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193510/while-android-studio-updated-to-v3-3-getting-api-variant-getassemble-is-obso), but didn't make any progress. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I [found a potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54442409/961743) that has resolved the warning. Below is the code I am using. Leaving the question for now in case there is a better solution.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.getAssembleProvider().get().doLast {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def apk = variant.outputs[0].outputFile
            File versionInfo = new File(apk.parent, "versionInfo.properties")
            versionInfo.text = "versionCode=${android.defaultConfig.versionCode}\nversionName=${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
            copy {
                from "${versionInfo}"
                into "$project.projectDir/temp_archive"
            }
        }
    }
}
```